# How can I get Jenkins to upgrade automatically on Windows64?

Tags: jenkins

I am setting up Jenkins on a Windows 64 bit machine. It's configured to run as a windows service.

Jenkins 1.482

I have another issue with using svn with jenkins and in trying to solve that issue i am trying to upgrade jenkins.

The upgrade fails with:

> Checking internet connectivity Checking update center connectivity
>   java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect at
>   java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method) at
>   java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source) at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source) at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source) at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) at
>   java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) at
>   java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) at
>   java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source) at

and

> hudson.util.IOException2: Failed to download from
>   http://updates.jenkins-ci.org/download/war/1.484/jenkins.war  at
>   hudson.model.UpdateCenter$UpdateCenterConfiguration.download(UpdateCenter.java:716)
>     at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$DownloadJob._run(UpdateCenter.java:1052)
>     at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$DownloadJob.run(UpdateCenter.java:1031)
>     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)

I am not sure what is wrong.
This fails when running as a service and when running as an exe in my user space.

Can anyone explain how to fix this issue so i can upgrade jenkins and then fix the svn plugin?

Comment: Does your server have external internet access? Can you navigate to http://jenkins-ci.org from a browser on the server? Do you have any antivirus software running on the server? Is the server firewall enabled?

Comment: It's windows 7 pro.  No antivirus.  I can reach the internet.  I can also do gets from SVN on my user account.

Comment: Do you have UAC enabled? Can you disable it and check if you have the same issue?

Comment: I think it is on - I will try that.